# Is SmoothDivScroll 1.2 working in IE 6, 7 and 8?

Tags: smoothing, smooth-scrolling

SmoothDivScroll is wonderfull script! But does anyone know if the new beta version of SmoothDivScroll (version 1.2) is working in IE 6, 7 and 8? I saw in the google Group of Thomas Kahn that this questions was also raised. I'm trying to get it working but can't get some features working and I don't know if it is my mistake or not. I hope Thomas himself sees this post and will react on it. And if the conclusion is that it is not working on these versions of IE, I would like to know if Thomas will work to get it also on IE working or if he leaves it as it is now. Of course I hope this, because it is wonderful code!

Jan

Comment: I wish this user would check his/her posts ;-(

Answer (score 1):

Yes, SmoothDivScroll 1.2 should work OK in older versions of Internet Explorer. I don't have a computer that is old enough to have a "real" installation of IE6 but I do have a virtual machine running Windows XP SP3 and Internet Explorer 6 (which is basically the same thing as a real installation).

When I tested on this machine there was one issue that had to do with the height of the hotspots. For some reason the hotspots do not fill out the entire height of the scrollable area. Currently I have no fix and to be perfectly honest I don't think I will spend time looking for a solution since IE6 is a browser that is becoming more and more marginalized. If anyone has a solution - let me knoe! I haven't made up my mind about IE7 yet. But I do want it to work fine in IE8 and IE9 though since these two versions are alive and kicking.

**Two follow up questions:**

1. **Which features** are not working and in **what versions** of
   Internet Explorer?
2. **Do you have a demo** somewhere that I can look at? Since
   SmoothDivScroll is a plugin that depends heavily on the surrounding
   code on the page, in many cases errors in the HTML and/or the CSS is
   the source of the errors.

Then again - sometimes the bungling is on my part. It's been known to happen. :-)